# Most likely a simple fix. Trying to remove items from a listbox with FOR loops.

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, listbox, session-variables

Trying to implement two "remove" buttons into my website that asks for the following:

"Add two buttons which will provide Remove functionality for the selected ListBoxes (you should be able to remove selected snacks and selected movies)"

My code so far is this

```
protected void bntReviewRemoveSnack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int intCounter = lbRvSnacks.Items.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
    {
        if (lbRvSnacks.Items[intCounter].Selected) // if the snack is selected
        { // remove the listitem to the lbSelected listbox
            lbRvSnacks.Items.Remove(lbRvSnacks.Items[intCounter]);
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the selected snack listbox id to "lbRvSnacks" and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly is this code not working?

Comment: It claims that "lbRvSnacks"

Comment: Sorry.. does not exist in the current context

Comment: Server Error in '/asppub' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'U6-L3 Page Preview' is not a valid identifier.

Source Error:


Line 24:         </style>
Line 25: </asp:Content>
Line 26: <asp:Content ID="U6-L3 Page Preview" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
Line 27:     <h2>
Line 28:         Ryan Ring - Assignment 6 - Point of Sales review


This is my error

Comment: The error you've posted has absolutely nothing to do with the code above. Your ID for the `<asp:Content />` element contains spaces and dashes, which is not allowed: `Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.`